# Raise flag if date exceeds 24 hours excluding weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case, date-arithmetic

I have an adjusted requirement to my previous question which GMB was able to help resolve.

What the below query needs to also exclude are the weekend days (Saturday and Sunday)

```
select  s.*,
        case when enddte > dateadd(hh, 24, begindte) 
           then 1 
           else 0 
        end as flag
from shipment s
where ship_id = 14723
```

Basically, if an entry with dateadd was inserted on Friday at 3 PM, the '1' flag shouldn't be raised on Saturday 3 PM but anytime after Monday 3 PM

Comment: What database are you using, and what is shipment's schema, please?

Comment: I am using MSSQL.   As for the fields for the shipment table, enddte and begindte are datetime fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the offset according to the day of the week of `begindte`:

```
set datefirst 1; -- Monday
select s.*,
    case when enddte > dateadd(
        day, 
        case datepart(weekday, begindte)
            when 5 then 3   -- friday:    add 3 days
            when 6 then 2   -- saturday : add 2 day
            else 1          -- else:      add 1 day
        end,
        begindte
    ) then 1 else 0 end as flag
from shipment s
where ship_id = 14723;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your query with:

```
DATENAME(weekday,date)

Returns the weekday name for date entered (Sunday,Monday, …,Saturday).
```

Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/101790).

So basically it is something like this:

```
select  s.*,
        case when enddte > dateadd(hh, 24, begindte) AND (DATENAME(weekday, enddte  ) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday') OR (DATENAME(weekday, begindte ) = 'Friday' AND enddte > dateadd(hh, 72, begindte)))
           then 1 
           else 0 
        end as flag
from shipment s
where ship_id = 14723
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using MSSQL which doesn't support the DAYOFWEEK function

Comment: I have found GMBs suggestion to be working. When I just tested yours, it the flag was raised (1) even though it shouldn't.    

Here are the dates for this example. 
dateadd: 2020-10-16 14:20:22.000 
enddte: 2020-10-19 07:04:45.000

Comment: @VQB does `begindte` has records in weekEnd days such as Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: no. Last entries for the week are entered on Friday. Hence me providing with the above date example on October 16 while the enddte is on Monday Oct 19.

Comment: @VQB of ok you are already calculating eddate to be on Monday on that occasion. I will edit my answer in a moment.

Comment: @VQB ok answer edited accordingly. The only day you actually have a problem is Friday, because you have to check if enddate is larger than the expected day at Monday

Comment: I tested the latest revised query and it is partially working. Considering days only it's working (Friday to Saturday works) but not by hours. 

Below are the actual results
begindte (Fri): 2020-10-09 17:41:31.000 enddte (Mon):2020-10-12 14:53:20.000 result flag = 1
begindte (Fri): 2020-10-09 17:41:38.000 enddte (Mon):2020-10-12 05:16:47.0000     result flag = 1
begindte (Fri): 2020-10-09 17:41:20.000 enddte (Sat):2020-10-10 17:55:17.000 result flag = 0
begindte (Fri): 2020-10-09 17:41:32.000 enddte (Sat):2020-10-10 17:08:01.000 result flag = 0